# Assign maximum memory limit for a particular database in sql server

Tags: sql-server, memory, resource-governor

In my SQL-Server instance, there are many databases. I want to restrict the memory size of each database (for example 8 GB). When I tried using Resource Governor, there are options like `max_memory_percent` and `min_memory_percent` and it is given in percentage value (values from 0 to 100). But I want to give the database size explicitly in GB and it should not go beyond that maximum limit.

Is there any way to restrict the database size or to get alerts if the database size exceeds the limit?

Can I implement this using Resource Governor?

[ALTER RESOURCE POOL](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb934024.aspx)

Comment: The RG setting that controls memory only applies to query memory, not buffer pool. The documentation is incredibly deceiving in that respect. I don't believe it's currently possible to limit memory by database. You'd have to separate them into their own instances.

Comment: What goal are you trying to complete?

Answer (score 1):

There is no way to limit the amount of memory a specific database takes.  SQL Server uses a least used / first evicted from memory policy (basically).

Answer (score -1):

You can assign minimum and maximum memory in MB for an instance from SQL Server Management Studio using inbuilt functionality. The steps are as follows:

1. Right click on the instance name and click on Properties.
2. Select Memory page.
3. Assign minimum and maximum memory in MB.

Please let me know if this is in line with what you intend to do.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. You have given the method for assigning memory for an instance.IS there any way to set the memory limit for each database.